# git merge again after merge and revert

Tags: git

I did git merge to rebase my branch to master and then due to some reason revert that merge (also pushed to remote).

Now I am trying to merge it again but it says "Already Up-to-date".
I manually verified that my branch didnt have changes present in master.

How should I fix this.

Comment: You should revert your previous revert.

Comment: Thanks , I did using git revert and git push , now after some changes I wanted to rebase again

Comment: You can't rebase, it's already merged, there is no branch to merge from. You need to revert your revert.

Comment: Thanks, let me try that

Comment: Reverting the 'revert' worked fine , Thanks. But wanted to understand why merge and then revert,  and merge again says' already update'

Comment: There is nothing to merge because the branch is already on the history of your current commit.